# Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in empty table

Tags: php, mysql, database, duplicates

I am currently starting web development and am now working on a very simple script that posts entry data from a from to a mysql database. But the problem I have been encountering is that when I submit the form I get the following error:

```
Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

To me it seems a really weird error as the table is completely empty, ID is set to auto_increment and I am not trying to assign any value to it.

I am using Xampp for my localhost on Mac OS btw.

This is my form (.php):

[image]

This is my mysql entry script (.php):

[image]

The result is this:

[image]

This is the database setup:

[image]

The weird thing is that when the table is empty, and I insert through the form the first time, something does end up in the database. But it is missing "email" and "password" and shows "NULL". The second time I use the form, nothing is added in the database:

[image]

Comment: Please put any codes as text or links to texts, nobody has time to re-type it in order to debug it for you. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/tour and this may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: you doing 3 inserts first one will work and add key 0 2nd will fail due to the duplicate - you shouldn't be doing 3 inserts regardless, just 1

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `id` column does *not* seem to be auto-incrementing. It is not generating a new id for every row. It just defaults to `0` if you don't supply a value for it.
2. Nonetheless there's a `UNIQUE`/`PRIMARY` constraint on that column, so the id `0` cannot occur more than once. Since you're not supplying an id and MySQL isn't generating one (because the column isn't auto-incrementing), you cannot insert more than one row.
3. You're issuing three separate `INSERT INTO` statements which will result in three separate rows to be inserted (*if* you could insert more than one row, see above), each with a different value set; but never one row with all values set.

So:

1. Make your `id` column actually auto-incrementing.
2. Prepare a single `INSERT INTO` statement which inserts all values in one go:

   ```
   INSERT INTO members (name, email, password) VALUES (.., .., ..)
   ```
3. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and stop using `mysql_*`. Learn about prepared statements, read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) for why.